# Why is someone's name on a glowing blue flower?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

During *Fortnite* Season 3 Chapter 3, I came across a glowing blue flower that had someone's name over it. Destroying the flower didn't get rid of the name. What does the flower do and why is someone's name over it?

[image: blue flower with someone's name]